# Mongodb + Node: When to close

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, koa

I am working on a Koa + Mongodb backend. My question is: When should I close the db, or does Mongodb manage that because I am not closing any of them right now and it seems fine.

```js
// app.js
const Koa = require('koa')
const database = require('./database')
const app = new Koa()
database
.connet()
.then(() => {app.listen(':8080')})
.catch((err) => {console.error(err)})
 

// ./database.js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient 
const Model = require('./model')

class Database {
 async connect() {
  if (!db) {
    db = await  MongoClient.connect("localhost:27017")
    this.item = new Model(db, 'item_collection')
  }
 }
}

module.exports = new Database()

// ./model.js
class Model {
  constructor(db, collectionName) {
    this.name = collectionName
    this.database = database
  }
  async findAll() {
   const result = await this.db.collection(this.name).find().toArray()
   if (!result) {
    throw new Error('error')
   }
   return result
  }
}

module.exports = Model
```

I also ran a stress test using vegeta to make API request to the server at 100 request / second and the response time is good. So, am I worried about premature optimization here? If not, when should I close the db?

Answer (score 1):

As Koa keeps running (and in your case listening on port 8080) you should ***not*** close the db connection.

If you are running scripts that are expected to end (tasks running on cron, etc) you should manually close the connection when you are finished with all of your db tasks.

You can take a look at [this example](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mongodb) for express.js (Koa's sister framework)